# How to get Amazon's add to cart confirmation page to display the mobile version

Tags: mobile-website, amazon-product-api

I have been following the docs for Amazons product advertising API and have created this URL to add a particular item to a cart:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html?ASIN.1=B07DD9TQSG&&Quantity.1=1

There are no issues with this on desktop, however whenever I open this link on mobile, it displays the desktop version of the page.

Is there any way around this?